# Can UIActivityIndicator be hidden?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiactivityindicatorview, activity-indicator

So I'm trying to use a UIActivityIndicator when I am connecting to a web service. What I wanted to happen is to hide the activity indicator by default (eg. in viewDidLoad method) but I don't know how.

I only want to show the activity indicator and start its animation when a connection is ongoing between the app and the web service. When the connection is over, I want to hide the activity indicator again.

Is it possible?

Comment: Taking a look into the documentation clears this up in a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop and hide the activity indicator using the code:

```
activityIndicator.hidden = YES;
[activityIndicator stopAnimating];
```

You can start and show the activity indicator by using:

```
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure.  Set the hidesWhenStoppedAttribute, and stop it when you want to hide it:

```
        UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(wp.width/2, wp.y+35, 20, 20)];
        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = [appDelegate getActivityIndicatorColor];
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = TRUE;
        [activityIndicator startAnimating];
        [coverView addSubview:activityIndicator];
```

P.S. Look at the NetworkActivityIndicator too.